# highlight the search text in AutoCompleteTextView dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have implemented `AutoCompleteTextView` for the search field in my application.

I want to highlight the text entered in the `AutoCompleteTextView`(the search text field) to be highlighted in the drop down list.

For example, if the user starts entering `'jo'` the drop down will have the following

```
joe smith
Joseph ahraham
billy Joseph
...
```

i want to highlight `'jo'` in all three names with color blue.

Comment: Best of My Knowledge ,This feature is not natively available in Android, you need to build your own component to achieve this task.

Comment: Thanks for the response KPBird. I will look for other options.

Comment: @Visa did u find any solution for this, i am also trying the same thing you wanted to achieve , if you found anything as such please help me by sharing it. Thanks

Comment: Have you find any answer for this ?

Comment: Please read my answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119113/autocomplete-textbox-highlighting-the-typed-character-in-the-suggestion-list/30158346#30158346

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still relevant: you should be able to achieve this by inserting `<b>`-tags and/or `<span>`-tags with color-definition into the data of your adapter around the words that should be highlighted.