# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list text highlighted according to search text

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have implemented `AutoCompleteTextView` for the search field in my application.

I want to highlight the text entered in the `AutoCompleteTextView`(the search text field) to be highlighted in the drop down list. How can I do this?.

Comment: so far i can customize the whole text suggestion, but not the specific characters which have been typed

Comment: e.g. if I type "ca" in the box and the suggestion is "Canada", then i can make "Canada" bold but not "ca" which i want

Comment: Please read my answer here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119113/autocomplete-textbox-highlighting-the-typed-character-in-the-suggestion-list/30158346#30158346

Answer (score 2):

So, In your `getView` method add the following

```
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myTv.setText(spanText);
```

Comment: I am not using custom view. I am using auto complete textView(Default android)

Comment: I am using custom adapter.. where can I get "textString"???
newSpannable(textString);