# how to change suggetion textcolor in autocomplete textview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I use AutoCompleteTextView for suggesting data based on what I entered.

I want to change the character color of text entered and show suggestions in a drop-down list.

[image: reference image]

How can I change the suggested word's text color or change its background to match the edit text?

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColorHint="@color/red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and

```
 autocomplete_country = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
    options.add("america");
    options.add("england");
    options.add("australia");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_tv, options);
    autocomplete_country.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use android:popupBackground attributes in AutoCompleteTextView in layout XML.Customize it to your needs

refer this link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:popupBackground

UPDATE:

you can refer this link .uses a custom adapter

[Autocomplete textbox highlighting the typed character in the suggestion list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119113/autocomplete-textbox-highlighting-the-typed-character-in-the-suggestion-list)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use AutoCompleteTextView due to restriction. You can create simple layout which contains EditText with RecyclerView. Attach text watcher for text changes. And finally change your matched characters with SpannableString.